# Why am getting this error when I try to install Emma?

Tags: apt, sql

I get the following error when I try to install Emma, how can I resolve this problem?

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved

This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

emma: Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~) but it is a virtual package
      Depends: python-mysqldb (>= 1.2.1-p2-2) but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.6-1) but 2.24.0-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
      Depends: python-glade2 (>= 2.8.6-1) but 2.24.0-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are u using ?

Comment: Am using version 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working now, all i did was to enable enable the following [Ticked the first and fourth box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzTl3.png)